# When not to use a comma wtih adjectives

Tags: adjectives

The river was a calm, crystal-clear vein of peace.

Should there be a comma after calm or not?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, calm and crystal-clear are coordinate adjectives, which must be separated by commas. Make sure not to put a comma after crystal-clear, though.

Answer (score -1):

> [1] *The river was a calm, crystal-clear vein of peace*.
>
> [2] *The river was a calm crystal-clear vein of peace*.

[1] and [2] have slightly different meanings.

Punctuation distinguishes coordination from the stacking of modifiers. In [1]  "vein of peace" is modified by a coordination of adjectives, giving the meaning "vein of peace that is both crystal-clear and calm".

By contrast, in [2] there are two layers of modification: "vein of peace" is modified by "crystal clear" to form the nominal "crystal-clear vein of peace", and this in turn is modified by "calm", giving the meaning "vein of peace that is calm by the standards normally applicable to crystal-clear ones".

Comment: This is indisputably wrong. They're not acting as cumulative modifiers; they're coordinate.

Comment: Wake up @AleksandrH   I said that [1] is a coordination. The other is stacking, not coordination..

Comment: To clarify, you're claiming that [2] is valid if the adjectives are treated as cumulative. But that doesn't make sense in this case. I think it's a stretch.